# NAS with eMule and IP blacklists support

Tags: nas, p2p

There are bunch of ready-made home NAS appliances that claim to handle downloads via eDonkey network (eMule, MLDonkey, etc.) I wonder if any of them can automatically download and apply P2P IP blacklists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that Synology NASes [support](http://forum.synology.com/enu/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=11795) eMule's ipfilter.dat and there is a [3rd party app](http://www.synology-wiki.de/index.php/AMule_IP-Filter_Download_als_3rd-Party_Applikation) to download the IP block lists automatically.